# How to allow permission to my new github account

Tags: git, github

I just changed my Github account fully. I have uninstalled GIt and installed it afresh and setup user.name and user.email afresh but it still denies me permission to push my contents to my repository sighting the old username (johnngondi).

GIT Reposity
    $ git remote add origin https://github.com/aliesoft/alienspine.git

Push request

```
$ git push -u origin master

remote: Permission to aliesoft/alienspine.git denied to **johnngondi**.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/aliesoft/alienspine.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Here is the GIT config list

```
$ git config --list
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=false
credential.helper=manager
gui.recentrepo=C:/Users/AlienSoft Tech/GIT
user.email=aliensofttechnologies@gmail.com
user.name=AlieSoft Technologies
color.ui=true
core.editor=emacs
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/aliesoft/alienspine.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

I have checked the origin repository and its showing this

```
$ git config --get remote.origin.url
https://github.com/aliesoft/alienspine.git
```

When I test the key I generated, its telling that the connection Successful.

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi aliesoft! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

How do I make it stop using that old username **johnngondi**?

Comment: My final resolve was to download Github for desktop. I still would like to use command line. So, if you find a solution post your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem:

`$ git config --get remote.origin.url
https://github.com/aliesoft/alienspine.git`

You are using the HTTPS protocol. You can try to use public and private RSA keys to access your git repository. A tutorial on how to generate and add your public key to your profile can be found here: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

After setting up the SSH key, try to push your code to `git@github.aliesoft/alienspine.git`. Change your remote origin with:

`git remote set-url origin git@github.com:aliesoft/alienspine.git`

Comment: Thank-you Larry, let me try it.

Comment: I have done that and it is still failing 

`$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 1129`

I added Key

`$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Identity added: /c/Users/AlienSoft Tech/.ssh/id_rsa (aliensofttechnologies@gmail.com)`

I have changed the Repository
`$ git remote set-url origin git@github.aliesoft/alienspine.git`

After pushing this was the response

`$ git push -u origin master
fatal: 'git@github.aliesoft/alienspine.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exist.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it